# Hangs waiting for URL / cache in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, freeze

I found that Chrome is hangs on browsing.

On hang some URL is reported "waiting" in Chrome status bar:

[image]

URL is random, and messages are also different

Sometimes it is

`Waiting for cache`

Also waiting animation constantly runs at page tab:

[image]

Waiting never ends.

Looks like I encounter some limit of connections or something.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Try `Control Panel \ Internet Options`, then tab `Connections`, button `LAN settings`, clear the tick on `Automatically detect settings`.

Comment: Why would it affect?

Comment: I'll be honest and say I don't know how in detail. I just had Chrome once performing slowly and this worked out my problem. I hope it does the same for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by:

## Clearing Cookies and Plugin Data

1. Settings
2. Search "Clear browsing data"
3. Check only the 'Cookies and other site and plugin data' box
4. Select 'the beginning of time' from the drop down
5. Click 'Clear browsing data'

If that doesn't work for you, you can try the following:

## Disable Flash Player

1. Settings
2. Search "plugins"
3. Content Settings
4. Manage individual plugins...
5. Flash Player
6. Disable

## Disable QUIC

1. Open chrome://flags
2. Search for 'QUIC'
3. Find "Experimental QUIC protocol Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android"
4. Select Disabled
5. Click the 'Restart Now' button.

Later I was able to go back in and re-enable Flash and QUIC and they worked fine.

Comment: If you are having a similar issue with error  'waiting for proxy tunnel' while machine's proxy setting is already set to 'auto detect', this could solve your issue and did solved for me.